# Why is the return value of this `ctypes` wrapper function `c_long(0)` and not `c_long(3)`?

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, ctypes, language-interoperability

Why is the return value of this `ctypes` wrapper function `c_long(0)` and not `c_long(3)`?

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

class AComplicatedCPPObj {

    int *d_;

public:

    explicit AComplicatedCPPObj(int *d)
            : d_(d) {
    }

    int *getD() const {
        return d_;
    }

    void setD(int *d) {
        d_ = d;
    }
};


#ifdef CTYPESTEST_EXPORTS
#if defined(_WIN64)
#define CTYPESTEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CTYPESTEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#endif

extern "C" {
CTYPESTEST_API AComplicatedCPPObj *AComplicatedCPPObj_new(int *d) {
    return new AComplicatedCPPObj(d);
}

CTYPESTEST_API int *AComplicatedCPPObj_getD(AComplicatedCPPObj *aComplicatedCppObj) {
    return aComplicatedCppObj->getD();
}

CTYPESTEST_API void AComplicatedCPPObj_setD(AComplicatedCPPObj *aComplicatedCppObj, int *d) {
    aComplicatedCppObj->setD(d);
}

}
```

The cmake script to compile into shared library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(ctypesTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(ctypesTest SHARED main.cpp)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/INSTALL)
add_definitions("-DCTYPESTEST_EXPORTS=TRUE")
install(TARGETS ctypesTest)
```

And on the python end:

```
import ctypes as ct
import os, glob, sys

WORKING_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# find the shared library
if sys.platform == "linux":
    so_path = os.path.join(WORKING_DIRECTORY, "INSTALL/lib/libctypesTest.so")
else:
    so_path = os.path.join(WORKING_DIRECTORY, "INSTALL/bin/ctypesTest.dll")

if not os.path.isfile(so_path):
    raise FileNotFoundError(so_path)

# load sharedd library into python
lib = ct.CDLL(so_path)


class AComplicatedCPPObj:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_new", [ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)], ct.c_void_p)
        # checking some ctyeps functions
        print("d", d, ct.c_int(d), ct.pointer(ct.c_int(d)), ct.pointer(ct.c_int(d)).contents)

        self.obj = lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_new(ct.pointer(ct.c_int(d)))

        self.set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_getD", [ct.c_void_p], ct.POINTER(ct.c_long))
        self.set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_setD", [ct.c_void_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_long)], None)

    def set_function_types(self, func_name, argtypes, restype):
        f = lib.__getattr__(func_name)
        f.argtypes = argtypes
        f.restype = restype

    def getD(self):
        return lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_getD(self.obj).contents

    def setD(self, d):
        if isinstance(d, str):
            d = d.encode()

        return lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_setD(self.obj, d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = AComplicatedCPPObj(3)
    print(o.getD())
```

This returns:

```
d 3 c_long(3) <__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x000001F66F0E8248> c_long(3)
c_long(0)
```

When I expect to see

```
d 3 c_long(3) <__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x000001F66F0E8248> c_long(3)
c_long(3)
```

## Edit - A mistake

I'm not sure what I've done differently now but it now appears the output I am getting when rerunning this code is this:

```
d 3 c_long(3) <__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x000002320B8A52C8> c_long(3)
c_long(193626992)
```

Also, as per a question in the comments, when I run:

```
x = 3
o = AComplicatedCPPObj(x)
print(o.getD())
```

The output is

```
d 3 c_long(3) <__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x000002320B8A5248> c_long(3)
c_long(193627312)
```

Which still isn't

```
d 3 c_long(3) <__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x000002320B8A52C8> c_long(3)
c_long(3)
```

?

Comment: What if `x = 3`, `o = AComplicatedCPPObj(x)`?

Comment: Hi Cristi, thanks (again) for the input, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a temporary pointer to a temporary object in this line:

```
self.obj = lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_new(ct.pointer(ct.c_int(d)))
```

After this line executes, the `pointer` and `c_int` objects are both released.  So you have undefined behavior.  The pointer passed to the function no longer exists.

I don't know why you want to pass pointers to objects around, but to fix what you are currently doing you need to keep a reference to the `c_int` object as long as the C++ code holds a pointer to it:

```py
import ctypes as ct

lib = ct.CDLL('./ctypesTest')

class AComplicatedCPPObj:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_new", [ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)], ct.c_void_p)
        self.set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_getD", [ct.c_void_p], ct.POINTER(ct.c_int))
        self.set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_setD", [ct.c_void_p, ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)], None)

        # keep reference to object and pass by reference to C++
        self.param = ct.c_int(d)
        self.obj = lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_new(ct.byref(self.param))

    def set_function_types(self, func_name, argtypes, restype):
        f = lib.__getattr__(func_name)
        f.argtypes = argtypes
        f.restype = restype

    def getD(self):
        return lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_getD(self.obj).contents

    def setD(self, d):
        # update local object and pass again by reference
        self.param = ct.c_int(d)
        return lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_setD(self.obj, ct.byref(self.param))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = AComplicatedCPPObj(3)
    print(o.getD())
```

But why not just pass the integer by value so memory doesn't have to be tracked??

Updated .cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class AComplicatedCPPObj {
    int d_;
public:
    explicit AComplicatedCPPObj(int d)
            : d_(d) {
    }
    int getD() const {
        return d_;
    }
    void setD(int d) {
        d_ = d;
    }
};

// FYI, _WIN32 is defined for both 32-bit and 64-bit windows, unlike _WIN64.
#if defined(_WIN32)
#   define CTYPESTEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define CTYPESTEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" {
    CTYPESTEST_API AComplicatedCPPObj *AComplicatedCPPObj_new(int d) {
        return new AComplicatedCPPObj(d);
    }

    CTYPESTEST_API int AComplicatedCPPObj_getD(AComplicatedCPPObj *aComplicatedCppObj) {
        return aComplicatedCppObj->getD();
    }

    CTYPESTEST_API void AComplicatedCPPObj_setD(AComplicatedCPPObj *aComplicatedCppObj, int d) {
        aComplicatedCppObj->setD(d);
    }
}
```

Updated Python:

```py
import ctypes as ct

lib = ct.CDLL('./ctypesTest')

def set_function_types(func_name, argtypes, restype):
    f = lib.__getattr__(func_name)
    f.argtypes = argtypes
    f.restype = restype

class AComplicatedCPPObj:

    def __init__(self, d):
        set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_new", [ct.c_int], ct.c_void_p)
        set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_getD", [ct.c_void_p], ct.c_int)
        set_function_types("AComplicatedCPPObj_setD", [ct.c_void_p, ct.c_int], None)
        self.obj = lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_new(d)

    def getD(self):
        return lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_getD(self.obj)

    def setD(self, d):
        return lib.AComplicatedCPPObj_setD(self.obj, d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = AComplicatedCPPObj(3)
    print(o.getD())
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - appreciate the answer. The reason I am passing int pointers around is just to learn how to do it. There is a good chance I'll have to  use this feature for some more complicated objects in a package I'm writing (or not who knows - I'm still figuring out the best way to use `ctypes`). I've also just realized that its possible to just use `ct.c_int64` for passing around pointers.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh Use pointers to pass around pointers. Used properly they maintain references to the Python/ctypes objects they they reference.  If you use integers you'll likely find your objects being delete before you want.